# Adding PCL library into Silverlight Application causes Error 2110

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-2012, silverlight-5.0, portable-class-library

I have a library that I have converted to a PCL in Visual Studio 2012. I have set the target frameworks to .NET Framework 4 and higher, Silverlight 4 and higher, Windows 8, and Windows Phone Silverlight 7 and higher. The library correctly compiles and is able to be integrated into a Visual Studio Project targeting .NET Framework 4.5.

I then add the PCL to a Silverlight 5 project. Before adding the PCL, it correctly builds. After adding it, it continues to build will no problem. However, when I launch it in Internet Explorer, I get the following error:

```
Line: 56
Error: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application 
Code: 2110    
Category: InitializeError       
Message: AG_E_UNKNOWN_ERROR
```

Ignoring the error or opening it in another browser simply brings up a white screen.

The error occurs before using the library. Simply adding the reference to the DLL seems to cause the problem.

I have not been able to find good documentation or help regarding what the error means.

Comment: Can you configure your Visual studio to break when such error occurs this way you can identify the actual problem where the error is.
See this link for more reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661121/silverlight-error-ag-e-unknown-error/1661206

Comment: Run the SL application with F5 (to make sure you're attached to the right iexplore process) and monitor the Output window in Visual Studio 2012. Don't forget to select 'Show output from Debug' in Output window. You might find something interesting, like a BadImageFormatException or so...

Comment: Did you happen to have a look at [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15124170/silverlight-toolkit-breaks-silverlight-5-application) ?

Comment: Can you try start debugging in OOB mode?